# How to tell Qt Network to change outgoing network interface?

Tags: linux, qt, routes, qtnetwork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to choose which Network interface to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725352/how-to-choose-which-network-interface-to-use)

My machine is connected to ethernet and wireless LAN.

Is there any way to tell Qt to use specified network as outgoing interface ?

Is there any c library functions in linux to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Use QNetworkAccessManager::setConfiguration for instance of your QNetworkAccessManager.

Doc: [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setConfiguration)