# Choosing network interface by app

Tags: c++, c, tcp, ip, nat

I'm a C/C++/Qt dev, and today, I have a particular need and I'm sure I'm not the only one. I need to choose with which network interface my computer app will connect to...

For example, I'm home, using a VPN to access some protected stuff (like a VPN used by my company). And I know I can't use the VPN to browse the Internet. I would like to be able to tell my FTP Client to connect to the VPN interface and my browser, to the classic interface (VPN may be a bad example, but the idea is there.)

As almost none of classical app one have on his computer, let the user choose which IP to, I would like to dev something which can do this for me and everybody who can need it, but I simply don't know where to begin. I know I'll have to hack, maybe intercept and relay the connection (Firewall like, or more NAT like), or maybe I can close and reopen the connection for the app (and STOP/CONT it to avoid it to notice, or anything else.

If you have any idea of how and where I can begin my research, it would be helpful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is normally handled by configuring which range of IP addresses should be sought via the VPN, and which ones should be sought via a local router etc.. Your operating system should have a tool for this, e.g. "route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1".  Is there a reason you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: You should be able to just configure the routing you want for the relevant IP ranges at the OS level. Search for 'routing tables'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to choose which Network interface to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725352/how-to-choose-which-network-interface-to-use)

Comment: @TonyD: I want to do this not only with VPN, but with 2 or more different interfaces (Ethernet and/or wifi and/or 3G), and to choose by app and not by IP range. There is many reason, bypass school security (i'm not at school anymore but they used to block google), "sandbox" my web browser, splitting my interface usage (torrent on wifi, web on ethernet for example)

Comment: @bames53: As I said to Tony_D, I would like a way to do it "by app" and not depending on the IP range. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @n.m.: Thank you but I know how to dev an app which will bind and listen on a specific IP. I want a way to do it for any app which don't implement any choice.

Comment: The accepted answer to the quoted question has all the information. I shall repeat it here for convenience: you don't, you can't and you shouldn't, it's the OS's job. There is nothing more to say about it, really.

Comment: Based on your examples, you should bind your socket to a specific IP, not a specific interface (which is impossible).

Comment: Correction: you should bind your socket to a specific IP *and* set up source-based routing on your computer. There are some howtos for Linux on the net for this. I'm not sure how to do this on Windows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23486/discussion-between-max13-and-n-m)